# jQuery fade in page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scope

I am trying to hook some jQuery to my nav to fade in and out the page wrapper when someone click on a main nav link. The code itself is working fine, but just have 2 issues:

- There is a flash in beggining like it loads everything, removes it,
  then fades it in (not sure if this is CSS related).
- The links are broken. For example: when you click "contact" instead
  of going to www.domain.com/contact it goes to
  www.domain.com/undefiend

Any help would be great. Thanks!!

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-wrap').css('display', 'none');
    $('#page-wrap').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

    $('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('#page-wrap').fadeOut(1000, newpage);
    });

    function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```

The code for the Nav (using wordpress)

```
<div id="nav_wrap">
    <div id="nav"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu',) ); ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do the links work before this? It sounds like your href is wrong from the start, this doesn't change anything about that.

Comment: Can you post the code were "contact" is?

Comment: ya, if I remove the section on JS the navigation works just fine. And when you hover on the links at the bottom (in chrome) it tells you the the link is right but when clicked it goes to "undefined"

Comment: @Sergio I edit the original post to show the nav code

Comment: @Packy, I saw that, good. Do provide code so all can help better next time. Good you got your question answered!

Comment: @Sergio ya I got the flickering nailed, but the link is still broken. Looking at the JS I can see why when I add this script the links break to /undefined. Not sure if it is Wordpress related.

Comment: @Packy, why did you accept the answer if you still have errors? comment that on falsarella's answer and maybe he can help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap" style="display: none;">
    ...
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-wrap').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);

    $('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newLocation = this.href;
        $('#page-wrap').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            window.location = newLocation;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the flicker perfectly. Nice and simple.

Comment: the href should be grabbed like this:

    var newLocation = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: @ChrisMcJava That would be the jQuery way. Generally, the changes I do to the OP's scripts are as least as I think it is possible to achieve the solution (so the answer is focused on it). Furthermore, it might be not necessary to use jQuery in this case... Have you had any compatibility issue using `this.href`? Thanks!