# Page FadeIn and FadeOut Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, transition, fade

I am currently trying to create a script that makes fading transition from page to page when clicking a anchorlink. I have already made the script, but it does not seem to work.

My code look like this:

```
$("body").load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(200);
});

$("a").click(function() {
    $link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").fadeOut(200);
    window.location.replace($link);
});
```

It does not seem to make the fadeIn and fadeOut transitions. It is still the normal pageload.

Comment: It is not making the fade transitions. It looks like any other pageload.

Comment: the ajax load function needs the first parameter the link of the loaded html

Comment: you could maybe do this  : - `$("body").fadeOut(200);` the current page, -then `window.location.replace($link);` with a page that body's Css is `display:none` - and finally in the new page loadeed script,  when onload / docment.ready `$("body").fadeIn(200);` ... but honestly, i find that approach a little dirty.

Comment: you need to place the redirecting line in the complete function of fadeOut

Comment: Duplicated question. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891603/jquery-fade-in-page-load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hide the body of the page on page load then
you need to place the redirecting line in the complete function of `fadeOut`

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(200);
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("body").fadeOut(200,function(){
          window.location =  $link; 
        });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to hide the element initially, either with `.hide()` or with CSS `display:none;`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: To prevent initial flickering due to `hide()` triggered on DOM ready the CSS `display:none` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `setTimeout` to time the `window.location.replace()` to execute after the current `body` has faded like :

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.replace($link);
    },200);
    return false;
});
```

Remember to return `false` at then end of the function else the default action of the link click i.e. redirection precedes any other action associated with the anchor.

But, sincerely, this will give you a smooth fading effect from the current page but not a smooth effect on the redirected page unless it's implemented by you.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a non-Jquery version of this code, and what would the equivalent be on the destination page to fade it in?

Answer (score 0):

This is four years later, but just in case someone needs it. I agree with Roko about the flickering, so I initially hid the body with CSS instead of putting `.hide()` before the fade in effect:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

Also some have mentioned using `.fadeOut()`, but it doesn't work on Chrome. I switched to `.show()` and `.hide()` which seems to work great. It also animates all of the elements as it fades, which produces a need transition without a hefty jQuery plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').show(500);
    $("a").click(function() {
        $link = $(this).attr("href");
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace($link);
        },1000);
        $("body").hide(500);
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Lastly, I'm using this on a page that contains click-to-scroll navigation like most one-pagers, as well as opening new tabs with `target="_blank"`, so I changed `$("a")` to `$(".transition-link")` and added `class="transition-link"` to the links I want to navigate from.